# The use of の and がある when talking about health

Tags: grammar

Why do we say 高血圧**の**人 but 肺の病気**がある**人？

高血圧がある人 would be unnatural, would it?

If we are to use がある for people with a particular disease (which high blood pressure is not), why are ＡＩＤＳの人 and 糖尿病の人 ok but not ＡＩＤＳがある人 and not 糖尿病がある人？

Perhaps, it’s about a disease name… if there’s the name of a condition mentioned, then がある will not work… Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

It is because 高血圧 is not a disease for which physical presence is felt. As you guess, 高血圧があるひと is not natural but not impossible. For comparison,

- がんのあるひと is acceptable
- 腫瘍がある人 is quite normal
- 風邪のある人 is impossible
- 咳のある人 is acceptable

I suppose 肺の病気の人 is avoided in order not to use の-phrases consecutively. 病気の人 is normal for *a sick person* while 病気がある人 is basically the same but sounds more like *a person with particular (persistent) diseases*.

Answer (score 0):

肺の病気の人 is natural. There is a difference I can think of though.

私は病気だ is a quality of 私.

私は肺の病気だ has a different meaning, here you are specifying what kind of disease it is. (It's a lung disease for me)

肺の can't modify "病気だ" because it acts like a verb.

Similarly

◎私は花粉症です

○私は花粉症があります

◎私は花粉のアレルギーがあります

✕私は花粉のアレルギーです this means something else again

の can acomodate for both though, and I think the unnaturalness is just a tendency of English speakers to avoid repetition.